# Fetch and append player statistics to an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas

I am a new programmer in python, and I need a bit of help to structure my code.

```
game_schedule = (
    ('Daily Game Schedule', 'daily_game_schedule'), 
    ('Full Game Schedule', 'full_game_schedule'),
)

team_standings = (
    ('Overall Team Standings', 'overall_team_standings'),
    ('Playoff Team Standings', 'playoff_team_standings'), 
)

worksheets = (
    ('Game Schedule', game_schedule),
    ('Cumulative Player Stats', 'cumulative_player_stats'),
    ('Player Injuries', 'player_injuries'),
    ('Team Standings', team_standings),
)

def create_and_update_worksheets():
    """
    Add 'Player statistics' if the worksheet is not in file_name. 
    Otherwise, it will update the worksheet itself.
    """

    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name, engine='openpyxl')

    for key, value in worksheets:
        start_row = 0
        if isinstance(value, tuple):
            for subkey, subvalue in value:
                response = send_request('2017-2018-regular', subvalue).content
                df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
                df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

                df1.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row, header=None, \
                             index=False)
                df2.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row+2, index=False)
                start_row += len(df2) + 4
        else:
            response = send_request('2017-2018-regular', value).content
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
            df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

            df1.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row, header=None, \
                         index=False)
            df2.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row+2, index=False)

    for sheet in writer.sheets.values():
        resize_columns(sheet)

    writer.save()
    writer.close()


create_and_update_worksheets()
```

I think there is repetitive code in the `for` loop `for key, value in worksheets:`. How can I change the structure so that it is not repetitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we can see these piece of code is repeated:

```
response = send_request('2017-2018-regular', value).content
df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

df1.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row, header=None, \
                     index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row+2, index=False)
```

you can define a function for it, it works like this:

```
def create_and_update_worksheets():
    def less_repetitive(value, start_row):
        response = send_request('2017-2018-regular', value).content
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
        df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

        df1.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row, header=None, \
                     index=False)
        df2.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row+2, index=False)
    ...
    for key, value in worksheets:
        ...
        if isinstance(value, tuple):
            for subkey, subvalue in value:
                less_repetitive(subvalue, start_row)
                start_row += len(df2) + 4
        else:
            less_repetitive(subvalue, start_row)
    ...
```

Another solution is change the `value` in `worksheets` to be all `tuple`, but I am not sure if it works. As you didn't use the `subkey`, in such situation those `value` is not `tuple` now, can be changed to `(('', value))`

and as you don't need use `subkey` just replace it with `_`
code works like this:

```
def create_and_update_worksheets():
    ...
    for key, value in worksheets:
        ...
        if not isinstance(value, tuple):
            value = (('',value))

        for _, subvalue in value:
            response = send_request('2017-2018-regular', subvalue).content
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(['Title'])
            df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.decode('utf-8')))

            df1.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row, header=None, \
                     index=False)
            df2.to_excel(writer, key, startrow=start_row+2, index=False)
            start_row += len(df2) + 4

    ...
```

Comment: I will show what is inside `worksheets`.

Comment: or you can do things like this: `if not isinstance(value, tuple):` `value = (('', value))` and if you don't need use `subkey`, just replace it with `_`

Comment: Could you modify your answer in considering that comment? I think I will accept your answer.